# RavenDB strange query result?

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I get a strange result on the following query:

**Query:** `Title:(Canon) AND Title:(75-300*) AND Title:(IS)`

**Result:** `Canon EF 75-300mm Zoom lens Mk III. Superb Condition.Perfect working Order`

However, this item doesn't have IS in its title.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word IS is a stop word, and has been removed.